# Can I declare an array of different length arrays in C without variable names?

Tags: arrays, c, initialization, declaration, compound-literals

I am trying to figure out if it's possible to do the following, but without having to declare the individual variables...

```
static char *set_list1[] = { "set", "one", NULL };
static char *set_list2[] = { "set", "one", "negative", NULL };
static char *set_list3[] = { "set", NULL };
static char *set_list4[] = { "set", "one", "new", "item", "here", NULL };
static char **set_list[] = { set_list1, set_list2, set_list3, set_list4, NULL };
```

Basically I need an array of pointers, each pointer then points to a variable length array of strings (which happen to be terminated with a NULL pointer.

Obviously I can declare it like the above, but is there a way to do this without having to declare each one with a name?

Intuitively this feels like it should work, but doesn't...

```
static char **my_array[] = {
    { "one", "two", NULL },
    { "another", NULL },
    { "more", "items", "here", NULL },
    NULL
};
```

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example in C23 you may use compound literals like

```
static char **my_array[] = {
    ( static char * [] ){ "one", "two", NULL },
    ( static char * [] ){ "another", NULL },
    ( static char * [] ){ "more", "items", "here", NULL },
    NULL
};
```

Or the same declaration but without the storage class specifier `static`

```
static char **my_array[] = {
    ( char * [] ){ "one", "two", NULL },
    ( char * [] ){ "another", NULL },
    ( char * [] ){ "more", "items", "here", NULL },
    NULL
};
```

Comment: You need to remember that compound literals only live as long as enclosing block.

Comment: @gulpr there is no need to mention that, Vlad is talking about C2X, where you can specify a storage class that will make it last forever (whose lifetime is not limited to the enclosing block).

Comment: I do not understand why bother with language version AND compiler. What is wrong with the example I wrote below, with the same values?

Comment: @arfneto If I am not mistaken the storage class specifier static within the compound literal is allowed only in C23.

Comment: You are right. I just believed `static` went there inside a series of trial and error. Now I see your point!

Answer (score 1):

Since C99 you can use compound literals to create unnamed objects. But until C23 you could not use storage class specifiers with compound literals. This feature is not widely supported currently (GCC 13 is the only one supporting it [as reported here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/compiler_support/23)).

In practice the lack of support for storage class specifiers is often not a problem.

For compound literals occurring inside a function body the storage duration is automatic, so the lifetime of such objects ends when the function body is exited. Note that calling a function from within another function does not exit the caller, so you can create an object with a compound literal in `main` and call functions which use that object.

For compound literals occurring outside of a function body the storage duration is static.

Here is a little example program showing how compound literals might be used.

```
#include <stdio.h>

// `my_array` and the objects it references have static duration.
char **my_array[] = {
    (char *[]){ "one", "two", NULL},
    (char *[]){ "another", NULL},
    (char *[]){ "more", "items", "here", NULL },
    NULL
};

void print_words(char **arr[]) {
    for (size_t i = 0; arr[i]; i++) {
        for (size_t j = 0; arr[i][j]; j++) {
            puts(arr[i][j]);
        }
    }
}

char ***make_my_array(void) {
    // These unnamed objects have static storage duration: C23 only.
    return (static char **[]){
        (static char *[]){ "one", "two", NULL},
        (static char *[]){ "another", NULL},
        (static char *[]){ "more", "items", "here", NULL },
        NULL
    };
}

int main(void) {
    puts("Printing `my_array`:");
    for (size_t i = 0; my_array[i]; i++) {
        for (size_t j = 0; my_array[i][j]; j++) {
            puts(my_array[i][j]);
        }
    }

    // `my_array_auto` and the objects it references have automatic storage duration.
    char **my_array_auto[] = {
        (char *[]){ "one", "two", NULL},
        (char *[]){ "another", NULL},
        (char *[]){ "more", "items", "here", NULL },
        NULL
    };

    putchar('\n');
    puts("Printing `my_array_auto` with a function:");
    print_words(my_array_auto);

    char ***my_array_c23 = make_my_array();
    puts("Printing `my_array_c23` with a function:");
    print_words(my_array_c23);
}
```

I tested [here on the Godbolt Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/76YzT5YGf) using GCC 13.2 to be sure that the C23 features are working.

Comment: I do not understand why bother with language version AND compiler. What is wrong with the example I wrote below, with the same values?

Comment: @arfneto -- _"why bother with language version AND compiler."_ Because storage class specifiers like `static` were not allowed for compound literals until C23, and AFAIK GCC 13 is the only common compiler that supports this new feature. The most recent versions of GCC I have installed on any of my machines are in the GCC 12 line, so I used Godbolt to compile code using that feature.

Comment: @arfneto -- I'm not sure that there is anything wrong with your example, but the objects created in your code by compound literals have automatic, not static, duration. This is fine, but there can be issues with the lifetime of objects created by compound literals for this reason. They can be made static by placement outside of any function, or by using `static` in C23. I didn't see other answers talking about the lifetime issues, which is why I wrote my answer.

Comment: Thanks for answering. This would never come to my mind ;) I am always thinking on ways to limit the scope and lifetime of variables, not the reverse. I saw the `static` there as a mistake for `const`.! My bad. If it was not the case, for sure.

Comment: @arfneto -- _"I saw the `static` as a mistake...."_ Maybe; I'm not sure at all that OP really needs `static` here and the question doesn't make it clear that `static` is needed. On the other hand, if OP tried to create the arrays in another function (as in my example `make_my_array`) without using the `static` class specifier then the resulting objects would not be valid after the function returned, and using those results would lead to undefined behavior.

Comment: at first I say this as a sort of poor JSON object :)

Answer (score 0):

You can just go on with this same concept, over and over again, as in

```
    const char** other_list[] = {
        (const char*[]){"set", "one", NULL},
        (const char*[]){"set", "one", "negative", NULL},
        (const char*[]){"set", NULL},
        (const char*[]){"set", "one", "new", NULL},
        (const char*[]){
            "set", "one", "new", "item", "here", NULL},
    NULL};
```

### a complete example

```
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77976322/can-i-declare-an-array-of-different-length-arrays-in-c-without-variable-names

#include <stdio.h>

int so_print(const char*[], const char*);

int main(void)
{
    const char** other_list[] = {
        (const char*[]){"set", "one", NULL},
        (const char*[]){"set", "one", "negative", NULL},
        (const char*[]){"set", NULL},
        (const char*[]){"set", "one", "new", NULL},
        (const char*[]){
            "set", "one", "new", "item", "here", NULL},
    NULL};

    size_t n_lists = 0;
    while (other_list[n_lists] != NULL) ++n_lists;
    printf("total of %llu lists\n", n_lists);
    if (n_lists == 0) return 0;
    for (size_t ix = 0; ix < n_lists; ++ix)
    {
        char msg[20];
        sprintf(msg,"\nList %llu:\n", ix);
        so_print(other_list[ix], msg);
    }
    return 0;
}

int so_print(const char* list[], const char* msg)
{
    if (msg != NULL) printf("%s", msg);
    size_t n_words = 0;
    while (list[n_words] != NULL)
    {
        printf("%llu\t%s\n", n_words, list[n_words]); 
        ++n_words;
    }
    printf("\n%llu words in this list\n", n_words); 
    return 0;
}
```

#### output

```
total of 5 lists

List 0:
0       set
1       one

2 words in this list

List 1:
0       set
1       one
2       negative

3 words in this list

List 2:
0       set

1 words in this list

List 3:
0       set
1       one
2       new

3 words in this list

List 4:
0       set
1       one
2       new
3       item
4       here

5 words in this list
```